# 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'loss' - When I used GridSearchCV to tuning my Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `tensorflow` and `keras` to build a simple MNIST classification model, and I want to fine tune my model, so I choose `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`.

However, when I call the `fit` function, it said:

`AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'loss'`

I compared my code to others', but still can't figure out why. The only difference is that I use `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`.

Here is my code:

```
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, Dropout, BatchNormalization
    from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
    from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

    ...
    ...
    ...


    def get_model(dropout_rate=0.2, hidden_units=512):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, input_shape=(28*28,)))
        model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
        model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
        model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
        model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
        return model

    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model, batch_size=128, epochs=10)
    para_dict = {'dropout_rate':[0.2,0.5,0.8], 'hidden_units':[128,256,512,1024]}
    clf = GridSearchCV(model, para_dict, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your build_model you havent added a loss function. Do that like:`model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `build_model` function above doesn't configure your `model` for training. You have added `loss` and other parameters.

You can compile the model by using keras sequential method `compile`. https://keras.io/models/sequential/

So your build_model function should be:

```
loss = 'binary_crossentropy' #https://keras.io/optimizers
optimizer = 'adam'           #https://keras.io/losses
metrics = ['accuracy']
def get_model(dropout_rate=0.2, hidden_units=512):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, input_shape=(28*28,)))
    model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss, metrics = metrics)
    return model
```

Comment: Thanks! But I encounter a new problem, when I call `fit` function, my model can finish training but fail to evaluate. The new exception is `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets`. My `y_train` is onehot vectors generated by `to_categorical` function, and my loss is `categorical_crossentropy`, metric is accuracy.

Comment: Do you have multi-label classification problem? @TomLeung Because using softmax for multi-label classification is not desirable. You can use all keras loss function as metrics. Like `metrics = ['categorical_crossentropy']`. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: I am dealing with a MNIST classification problem (10 classes), my last layer uses a `softmax` activation and my loss is `categorical_crossentropy`. But finally I manage to run the `fit` function by converting my `y_train` from onehot vectors to single integer labels. I don't understand why `sklearn` don't accept onehot vectors as labels, neither the difference between linear activation with categorical_crossentropy metric and softmax activation with accuracy metric. Could you explain me in detailed?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth  Does it sound a best practice to use drop out in the very first layer? I mean before the first dense layer? Why not after it?

Comment: I was just answering OP's question but dropout on the visible layer is not uncommon practice though I am not sure of the motivation here. Dropout on visible layer means you are ignoring a percentage of the inputs. Essentially you are sampling.